# Hide web pages to the search engines robots

Tags: url, hide, robots.txt, web-crawler

I need to hide all my sites pages to ALL the spider robots, except for the home page (www.site.com) that should be parsed from robots.

Does anyone knows how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to all pages you do not want to index tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`

or you can create `robots.txt` in your document root and put there something like:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /*
```